# Django's Settings Magic

Tags: python, django

I'm building an application that borrows some design ideas from Django - the use of a per-project manage.py and settings.py, for example- and am trying to decipher the magic.

When I want to refer to my Django settings, I generally import from django.settings. Obviously, though, my settings are in their own project-specific module. Any idea how this is accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An environment variable: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE points to your settings module.

You can use the `__import__` function: See [http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#**import**](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__)

And try, assuming your main app module is myapp:

```
myapp.settings = __import__(SETTINGS_MODULE_NAME, globals(), locals(), [], -1)
```

This is the dynamic equivalent of the `from module import *` statement

Comment: Sure, but what mechanism actually hooks that variable's value to django.settings? The source doesn't seem to have a settings module or package, and I'm pretty sure the contents of my settings.py are processed and added to (default vals, etc) before being injected into the django.settings (pseudo?-)module.

Comment: Awesome- I was just looking through importlib. Thanks!